# IE7+8 Animation bug, Background color + CSS3 Rounded corners

Tags: jquery, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css

I ran into an interesting issue at today, i'm developing the .js for site.

The site have some boxes with some round corners, the designer have made an active state where the background color animates from one color to another.

So i made a simple animate(), with jQuery-UI to animate the background color.

If you look at the pasted link, (in IE7/IE8) you will see that there is a flash, where the background color set's to white when you click the box, then start's the animation from white to the selected color.

http://temp.pumpthejuice.com/ie/rounded-corners.htm

i'm using http://css3pie.com/ for the round coners. There is also an box with no round corners that work fine..

Anybody know anything about this, have run into the issue, got an idea to a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: CSS3PIE is using the legacy (buggy) DirectX filter objects for transparency. Flashing white when layered is one of their many bugs.

Comment: could u just take a look at http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ i am using it and i don't have any problem with it

Comment: Thanks, i'll try the fetchak and see how that turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the many rounded corners stylesheets to avoid this type of issue with script based solutions:

- [borderstyles](http://battletech.hopto.org/html_tutorials/rounded_css_borders/more_styles.html)
- [chunky borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/chunky.html)
- [snazzy borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/snazzy2.html)
- [curved borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/curves.html)